# How to group data in a single column based on another column using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, sorting, vector, grouping, multiple-columns

I have 99940 data with three columns, 1st and 2nd column with id numbers and third column with a weight like the sketch data below. There are 441 unique id values which repeats in 1st and 2nd column. I want to group id1 such that every group has three consecutive values, and if the corresponding id2 has the same value as in id1 within the group, sum the weight.

```
data:
id1    id2     weight
1       3        10
1       4        10
1       7        10
1       8        10
2       1        10
2       5        10
3       2        10
4       3        10
4       6        10
5       3        10
6       4        10
7       2        10
8       1        10

result:
group(1)
id1    id2     weight   selected
1       3        10       Yes (Because group1 has 1,2,3 and id1 is 1 and id2 is 3)
1       4        10       No
1       7        10       No
1       8        10       No 
2       1        10       Yes (Because group1 has 1,2,3 and id1 is 2 and id2 is 1)
2       5        10       No 
3       2        10       Yes (Because group1 has 1,2,3 and id1 is 3 and id2 is 2)
Weight = 30

group(2)
4       3        10     No
4       6        10     Yes (Because group2 has 4,5,6 and id1 is 4 and id2 is 6)
5       3        10     No
6       4        10     Yes (Because group2 has 4,5,6 and id1 is 4 and id2 is 4)
Weight=20

group(3)
7       2        10     No
8       1        10     No
```

and so on.

I have tried using grouppixels, sortrows to implement the weight score and finding column values based on another column, but I am finding difficulties in making groups.

Comment: Also note your original data has `4       6        10` in row 9, so it _will_ be selected for weight and the weight for that group will be 20

Comment: Edited. Thanks again man :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `ismember` function like so:

First, identify the unique id1 values

```
id1 = data(:, 1);
unique_id1 = unique(id1, 'stable');
```

Then, loop over the unique ids in groups of 3, and extract the rows from `data` that match  any of the three ids.

```
weights = [];
groups = cell(0);
for ii = 1:3:length(unique_id1) - 2
    % Pull out just the id1 values in this group
    ids_in_group = unique_id1(ii:ii+2);
    
    % answer has 1 if id1 is in ids_in_group, 0 otherwise
    select_row_for_group = ismember(id1, ids_in_group);

    % Logical indexing, select only rows with 1 in select_row_for_group
    group_data = data(select_row_for_group, :);

    % Append new group to our cell array
    groups{end+1} = group_data;

    % Select a row in the group for weight calculation if its id2 is in ids_in_group
    select_row_for_weight = ismember(group_data(:, 2), ids_in_group);

    % Select only the weights we want
    selected_weights = group_data(select_row_for_weight, 3);

    % Sum the selected weights
    weightsum = sum(selected_weights);

    % Append to weights array
    weights(end+1) = weightsum; 
end
```

And now you have:

```
>> groups{1}

ans =

     1     3    10
     1     4    10
     1     7    10
     1     8    10
     2     1    10
     2     5    10
     3     2    10

>> groups{2}

ans =

     4     3    10
     4     6    10
     5     3    10
     6     4    10

>> groups{3}

ans =

     7     2    10
     8     1    10

>> weights

weights =

    30    20     0
```

Comment: This is a very neat implementation. Real cool. Thank you.

Comment: Also, If one id is missing in the group, Let's say group 3 has no values with id1 as 9, but only with 7 and 8, using unique will group 10 into group 3 right? Is there a way around it?

Comment: Do you mean you want group number to be equal to `ceil(id1 / 3)`? If so, do `for ii = 1:3:max(id1)-2` and `ids_in_group = ii:ii+2`

Comment: This guy is a genius.